# Typescript using mapped types with arrays

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use mapped types with typescript, which is supposed to be possible, but running into some issues.

Let's say I have 3 classes:

```js
class A {
    public foo1 = 1;
}
class B {
    public foo2 = 1;
}
class C {
    public foo3 = 1;
}

const base = [A, B, C] as const;
```

Basically, what I want is to pass `base` into some function, and get back an array with 3 matching instances.

```
type CTOR = new(...args: any[]) => any

function instantiate1<T extends ReadonlyArray<CTOR>>(arr: T): {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} {
    const items = arr.map(ctor => new ctor());
    return items as any; //Don't mind about breaking type safety inside the function
}
```

Now this returns:

```
const result1 = instantiate2(base) //type is [typeof A, typeof B, typeof C]
```

which makes sense, as I didn't really "map" the type yet, just made sure the syntax works.

However if I try to actually map the type:

```
function instantiate2<T extends ReadonlyArray<CTOR>>(arr: T): {[K in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[K]>} {
    const items = arr.map(ctor => new ctor());
    return items as any; //Don't mind about breaking type safety inside the function
}
```

I get an error that `T[K]` doesn't satisfy the constraint of instance type.

anyone as an idea for a workaround?

[full playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AZgPYkCM0AvNOQNxIC%20SokMAQoimlrgcWQBM1Wg2aso0AMJc0GHPkKkSAZhH0mSFiQB2EAC7RskAKYiA2rAA00djakBdaJGjBdBpPoCe6M1IAqAPIASiI6JgDuABQAdHFgAE4A5hAAXM46XuYOAJTUAHwZXlpEmDrA%20ni60Hh6%20mA6lWD6JuQAPP7QJgAeLToAJjDBJmD9uiBesAkJYF5tASH5%20VGJCen%20OekI5gDSNTrQANYmXiRE0P4O67sOjLJobnU1LQC2MDSrMS9g6FEVJAkCtBwhFXPoAVEcjkGHIEiZ9JgEgc8K8YC4Gl46NAAPTYgAiugA5IYXrV%20s5sCRMIZsHCwIdakloN5fNAIGAiPCvPsIHh%20mZ9AALMylcqVXSaJCiipVZF1BpNFqCDpdXomAZDEZjHQTKYzOYLYJLFbTdabRC7fZHE5nC5XaAASXl5RM-h8Jg6N3yd2QckeBmeJjeIk%2031%20-0BVEKILBEKhMLQcIRSMDwfRmSxuIJOmJ0FJAwpVJpdIZOiZLLM7M53h5fIFwuIZRlEuY2iecIgmBA%20koNFqBgVeGaJkEUWMEBMeVxFZqMHMFdt1mZ7ttdmXvltji0bYDHa7%20mEfedipHY9MU%20xM7wc6Xa63e%2075HMAAYHDFlPQcdikEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript, according to [microsoft/Typescript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  It's a fairly old issue now and is on the "Backlog", so I wouldn't expect it to be fixed anytime soon.

---

Workarounds:

Explicitly constrain `T[K]` to the desired constructor type.  I usually do this with the [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) like this:

```
declare function instantiate<T extends ReadonlyArray<Ctor>>(arr: T): {
    [K in keyof T]: InstanceType<Extract<T[K], Ctor>>
};

const result = instantiate(base);
// const result: readonly [A, B, C]
```

Or, you could replace the [`InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) with your own version that doesn't care if `T` is a constructor.  The [existing type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f67ee4437993bfcf469e72ae4a753a570300339c/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1541) is:

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = 
   T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

So you can loosen it to:

```
type MyInstanceType<T> = // no constraint on T
    T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

and then your original version works as expected:

```
declare function instantiate<T extends ReadonlyArray<Ctor>>(arr: T): {
    [K in keyof T]: MyInstanceType<T[K]>
};

const result = instantiate(base);
// const result: readonly [A, B, C]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AZgPYkCM0AvNOQNxIC+SokMAQoimlrgcWQBM1Wg2aso0AMJc0GHPkKkSAZhH0mSFiQB2EAC7RskAKYiA2rAA00djakBdaJGjBdBpPoCe6M1P0kAE4iOiYA7tAAFAB0sWCBAOYQAFzOOl7mDgCU1AB8aV5aSESYOsD6eLrQeHr6YDoVYPomADwAKtAmAB7NOgAmMABKJmB9uiBesIGBYF4t-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)